# Different count of account records when using Map

Tags: apex, map

I am working on a CSV data upload via email to apex where if the account record exists i need to get the Id and perform an upsert operation.
I am using Map to capture all the accounts and checking if the account with that name exists.

```
Map<String, Id> accountMap = new Map<String,Id>();
for(Account a:[SELECT Name,Id FROM Account]){
            accountMap.put(a.Name,a.Id);
        }
System.debug(accountMap.size());
```

The above debug statement gives me a count of 4919.

However when i execute the following statement

```
System.debug([SELECT count() FROM Account]);
```

I get a total count of 5048.

I executed both in anonymous apex, but map count giving a different result.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation i found that i had duplicate accounts. Hence the different count in Map vs SOQL count.

A validation rule created at a later stage prevented more accounts to be inserted with the same name.

Comment: Yep, that'd do it. Calling `.put()` on a map and using the same key will overwrite the value for that key. The `.put()` method does return an `Object`, so you could detect this happening by doing something like `Object result = myMap.put(key, value);` followed by `if(result != null){ system.debug('replaced value in map'); }` (`.put()` returns the previous value for the key if the key already existed in the map)